# Solving a 4 variable linear system equation with known coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

The knowledge is trivial and I'm kinda ashamed to ask, but I am not able to solve the following system using substitution or elimination.

$ λP_0 = μP_{1a} + μP_{1b} \\ μP_{1a} + λP_{1a} = λP_0 + μP_2 \\ 2μP_2 = λP_{1a} + λP_{1b} \\ P_0 + P_{1a} + P_{1b} + P_2 = 1 $

where λ,μ are known.

Do you have any recommendations?

P.S: It needs to be solved... by hand

Comment: I would suggest writing the problem out in matrix form $(A\textbf{x}=b)$ and then solve for $\textbf{x}$ - assuming you're allowed the help of computer packages

Comment: Thank you but it has to be done by hand...

Comment: To tack on to @Naji , see Gaussian Elimination, which for a 4 variable system is not so much a chore to do by hand.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Possible typo in the second equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can exploit the structure of the system to simplify a little and temporarily merge $P_{1a}+P_{1b}$.

$$\begin{cases}λP_0 &= μP_1 \\ 2μP_2 &= λP_1\\ P_0 + P_1+ P_2 &= 1 \end{cases}.$$

Then

$$\frac\mu\lambda P_1+P_1+\frac{\lambda}{2\mu}P_1=1$$ gives you $P_1=\dfrac{2\lambda\mu}{2\mu^2+2\lambda\mu+\lambda^2}$ and from there $P_0,P_2.$

Reintegrating the second equation of the initial system, you now have a simple $2\times2$ system to split $P_{1a},P_{1b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $λP_0 = μP_{1a} + μP_{1b}$ as $$λP_0 - μP_{1a} - μP_{1b} + 0P_2 = 0$$ 
$μP_{1a} + λP_{1a} = λP_0 + μP_2 $ as $$-  λP_0 +  (λ-μ)P_{1a} +0P_{1b} - μP_2 = 0$$
etc.

to get the matrix representation of the system as $Mx = a$ where

$M =\begin{pmatrix} 
λ  & -μ   & -μ &  0 \\
-λ & λ+μ  & 0  & -μ \\
0  & -λ   & -λ & 2μ \\
1  &  1   &  1 &  1  
\end{pmatrix} 
$,
$x = \begin{pmatrix} 
P_0\\
P_{1a}\\
P_{1b}\\
P_2
\end{pmatrix} 
$

and  $a = \begin{pmatrix} 
0\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} 
$
We will show how to replace rows of this matrix by combinations with other rows in order to obain a upper triangular matrix: First we see that the second row can be replaced by
the sum of itself and the first row. This can be expressed by multiplying with a matrix $D_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
 1& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
 0& 0& 0& 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$.Since the question generously left us a zero in the third row we only have to get rid of the first element of the fourth row. This is done by the matrix $D_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
 1& 0& 0& -λ \\
\end{pmatrix}$. There are still three more matrices, two for the zeroes of the second culumn and one form the zero of the third column (fourth row) they are : $D_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 1& 1& 0 \\
 0& 0& 0& 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, 
$D_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
 0& λ+μ& 0& λ \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $D_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
 0& 0& -(λ+μ)& 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$, this reduces your system to the set of equations 
$$ λP_0-μP_{1a}-μP_{1b} = 0 $$
$$ λP_{1a}-μP_{1b}-μP_2 = 0$$
$$ -(λ+m)λP_{1b}+μP_2  = 0$$
$$ (-λ^2-2λμ-2μ^2)P_2 = -λ^2 $$
From the last equation you can solve $P_2$, from the third $P_{1b}$, since $P_2$ is already known, and so on.